# Flow type annotation: why `ClassName<{}>`?

Tags: javascript, generics, react-native, flowtype

Creating a fresh React-Native project with `react-native init AwesomeProject`, I was confused by `<{}>` in this class declaration, in the generated App.js:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
```

Eventually I figured out that `<{}>` was a Flow type annotation for a [Class Generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/#toc-class-generics).

I am familiar with [generic types in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and understand the usefulness of them.

However, I am struggling to understand the purpose of the Flow annotation. What does it accomplish? As far as I can tell, it is validating that the `App` class will be of type `Object`. While that seems redundant, if that were the case then I would hope it would be written as `<Object>` as in this [react-native source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/Animated/src/createAnimatedComponent.js), at:

```
class AnimatedComponent extends React.Component<Object> {
```

The only reason I could find to explain the need for this type check is in the [MDN documentation for `extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends):

> The .prototype of the extension must be an Object or null.

Is `<{}>` a shorthand for `<Object>`? If that's the case, then it seems comparable to using an actual string in place of a type annotation specifying `string`, which seems wrong. For example:

```
// @flow
function concat(a: string, b: string) {
    return a + b;
}
// as compared to -->
// @flow
function concat(a: "foo", b: "bar") {
    return a + b;
}
```

1. What is the purpose of the `<{}>` annotation or what is it validating about the code?
2. Is `<{}>` equivalent to `<Object>`?
3. Am I misunderstanding something?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding 2: NO, because the `{}` annotation defines a sealed object type, whereas `Object` is unsealed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Objects (and functions) in Flow are structurally typed](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/#toc-objects-are-structurally-typed). This is to say that objects that match all the properties and types of a `{...}` type are subtypes of it. In the case of `{}`, this includes all true objects (so barring arrays and literals), and indeed `Object === {}`.

Your example with `string` is fundamentally different, because the literal types like `a: "foo"` are *only* those instances of strings, i.e. `"fo"` is not a subtype of `"foo"`.

As for the actual purpose of that generic, `Component` special-cased by the Flow typechecker, and in fact you can omit the generics altogether, as they can be inferred from the property types. The first generic parameter is the type of the props, the second is the type for the state. [See the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-adding-state).